# Can ELB manager public IP other that not belongs to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to know if it is possible the ELB manager others IP's that it is not from AWS, or EC2. Like, if I have some externtal IP's (others that it is not from Amazon) the ELB can reache then and load the traffic?
Best regards.

Comment: Are you asking if you can use AWS ELB to load balance traffic for on premise servers ? Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

The ELB does not support it. However, the ALB supports sending traffic to on-premises. A  VPN or AWS Direct Connect connection is required.

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancing-via-ip-address-to-aws-on-premises-resources/